# Find and click on all "follow" buttons in instagram using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, ui-automation

Hello Fellow Stack Overflow members and coders,

I am trying to make an automation script using Selenium WebDriver on Instagram where I want to follow every member a particular account is following.
I am stuck at a point where after navigating to user's profile (who's follower I want to follow) when I click on "following" link a new window opens and it contains all the members this user follows (as shown in following screenshot):
[Window opened after clicking "following" link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxpoi.jpg)

Now as you can see in above window only first few followers are initially loaded and then as you keep on scrolling down the users keeps on getting loaded.

I am completely lost here on how can I move the focus to this new jquery kind of window and keep on scrolling down until the full list is loaded and then find once full list is loaded, click on follow button for each user.

Your help would be really appreciated in this regard.

I have tried various options like moving the mouse over to the window and clicking at blank location and then using Keys.Arrow_Down multiple times, finding first Follow button and then keep on pressing down button etc but it doesn't seem to be right approach and it doesn't work. Kindly help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

what if you...

Using a while, get all the visible elements in a list, move using JavascriptExecutor to the last of the element in the list, and keep getting the elements(doing the same, moving to the last pos in the list) until you reach the number(this is the while condition) of following(or following-1 if he/she follows you)

```
(JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", webElementInList);
```

Comment: Thanks Yacdaniel, but I didn't quite get it. I am pretty beginner with Javascript and it would be great if you could please help with a code snippet.

Comment: i provide you the code snippet for the JavascriptExecutor, you just need to implement the logic.